# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding Resource Sequence

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Just realized that mvc model binder will collect all data from route parameters + query string data + form collection data.

And i want to know the sequence of the model binder choosing these resources.
In another word, if there are properties (say id, name) with same name in these 3, what is the priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i got the answer from a material.

The order is:

1. Request.Form
2. RouteData.Values
3. Request.QueryString
4. Request.Files

:)